# Test for equivalence after sampling into test groups

Tags: python, random-allocation, equivalence

I want to test the effects of different versions of treatment across multiple test groups of a given population.  In order to do that, I want to randomly sample my population into, let's say, 4 groups of 2000+ subjects each.

After sampling, I generally try to evaluate each group for equivalence prior to assigning treatment and executing the test.

My question is on how to test for equivalence. In the past I have used ANOVA to evaluate differences of mean on a given attribute (for example, AGE or CHRONIC_CONDITION Y/N), or I have used t-tests to evaluate differences in attribute distribution...remember the goal here is to ensure that my groups are as "equivalent" as possible.  However, I feel like there is probably a better way to measure similarity. ANOVA feels too squishy, and T-Tests become unmanageable with each version (for example, 4 groups would require 6 t-tests: AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD).

Are there better methods to evaluate sampled group equivalence or similarity?  Bonus question: a way to do it in Python?

Note: I've searched the archive but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. Happy to have another look if someone finds a thread.

Comment: Seems almost like a duplicate of: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124536/27276

Answer (score 1):

There are so-called equivalence tests. You will find related information on this site ([equivalence](/questions/tagged/equivalence)), for example, [How to test hypothesis of no group differences?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3038/27276).

However, note also that many believe that balance checking is senseless in randomized experiments (e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/199838/27276).

On a more practical side, your groups seem very large. Why would you expect any form of imbalance in truly randomized groups?

Last, [blocking](/questions/tagged/blocking) might also be an option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To answer your question, yes, there are occasions when samples are unbalanced. I am able to diagnose by evaluating a t-test against a particular metric (eg: age) and find the differences to be significant < 0.05. When I re-sample, the imbalance generally disappears.  This may be a product of faulty randomization in my library - I'm using the sampler included with pandas, a python library.  Without running the t-test, I would be at risk of moving forward with a test against imbalanced groups.

Comment: To rephrase https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/199838/27276 (see also the comments): In randomized assignments, we know by definition that groups are equal in the **population**. Thus, any significance test is senseless; if p < .05, it is a type I error.